# Field not writable after Database.rollback() and clone()

Tags: apex, master-detail, clone, transaction, rollback

This is my custom save method:

```
private void saveNewMode() {
    Savepoint toBeforeState = Database.setSavepoint();

    try {
        insert parent;

        for(ChildA__c prs : childrenA) {
            prs.mdr_Parent__c = parent.Id; <<<< ERROR here
        }
        insert childrenA;

        for(ChildB__c prt : childrenB) {
            prt.mdr_Parent__c = parent.Id;
        }
        insert childrenB;
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
        Database.rollback(toBeforeState);

        parent.Id = null;

        for(ChildA__c prs : childrenA) {
            prs = prs.clone(false, true);
        }

        for(ChildB__c prt : childrenB) {
            prt = prt.clone(false, true);
        }
    }
}
```

The following scenario fails with

> Field is not writeable: UP2GO_2F__ChildA__c.UP2GO_2F__mdr_Parent__c

in the line marked with `<<<< ERROR here` only in a customer org (cannot be reproduced in our Packaging DE org) in the following scenario:

1. Call custom edit page with above controller extension from a NEW scenario (=neighter paren nor children A, B, C are inserted)
2. Provoke a validation error in ChildrenB
3. Validation error is displayed in the page
4. User corrects error and hits save again
5. The above error is shown

**Note: The Field is a non reparentable Master Detail!**

I read every [single article](http://www.oyecode.com/2013/08/master-detail-fields-not-writable-how.html) [about the use of clone()](http://www.tehnrd.com/error-handling-savepoints-and-inserts/) [after a Database.rollback()](http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-master-detail-field-is-not-writeable-workaround.html) and tried every(?) single variant of SObject.clone(...) on the rolled back records and this error makes no sense to me.

No matter if I do clone(false, true), clone(false, false), clone(false, false, false, false) after the rollback (the one provoked by the validation error) I run into this problem.

Comment: what is the field type for `prs.mdr_Parent__c` is it by chance a formula field or a Master-Detail that cannot be reparented? Does the user have a license to the package where the field resides? I do not believe it has anything to do with a rollback as you have not rolled anything back where your error is.

Comment: Yes it is a non reparentable Master Detail Field .

Comment: Then if the record already has a parent that is why it is not writeable. You should add a check for the isUpdateable() to that part of the code.

Comment: But it is Not inserted yet I just rolled back every previous dml. The parent Id it might still have is invalid since the parent also was rolled back.

Comment: At the point where you marked the error is I do not see anywhere that you have rolled back....

Comment: The user provoke a validation rule error before (see question) and it was caught. Only then this error occurs. See the clone() in the catch is causing problems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22763/discussion-between-robert-sosemann-and-eric).

Answer (score 0):

Modifying my code like this the problem went away. The only thing I changed was the use of `clone(false, false)` on the parent and `deepClone(false, false)` on all child collections in my rollback catch block.

```
private void saveNewMode() {
    Savepoint toBeforeState = Database.setSavepoint();

    try {
        insert parent;

        for(ChildA__c prs : childrenA) {
            prs.mdr_Parent__c = parent.Id;
        }
        insert childrenA;

        for(ChildB__c prt : childrenB) {
            prt.mdr_Parent__c = parent.Id;
        }
        insert childrenB;
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
        Database.rollback(toBeforeState);

        parent = parent.clone(false, false);
        childrenA = childrenA.deepClone(false, false);
        childrenB = childrenB.deepClone(false, false);
    }
}
```